# SQL Server Management Studio problem creating scripts of procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

The stored procedure scripts that SQL Server Management Studio 2005 generates for me are like:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[APY_SP_ACH_Transmit_Finish]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
  ...
  print ''arg!, all the quotes are escaped''
  ...
 '
END
```

so all the quotes are escaped.  is there a way or option to turn this off?

in SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I do the following:

1) In Object Explorer, locate the procedure I want to script out
2) right click, and select script stored procedure as "Create To"
3) selecting file or clipboard has the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to happen when the scripting option `"Include If NOT EXISTS" clause` is on.

Do you need this on? If not you can turn it off via the

Tools -> Options -> Scripting

From [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/242799/ssms-certain-scripting-options-yield-dynamic-sql) it doesn't look configurable without that.